# ruby padding an array

Tags: ruby, padding

I'm getting the following error when I run my code from my rspec file:

```
pad pads element to the end of an array

Failure/Error: expect(pad(array,array.length + pad_size, 'apple')).to     eq(array+Array.new(pad_size, 'apple')) 

expected: ["apple", "apple", "apple",...]
```

my current code is:

```
def pad!(array, min_size, value = nil) #destructive

    difference = min_size-array.length

    difference.times {array << value} 

    array
end

def pad(array, min_size, value = nil) #non-destructive

    difference = min_size-array.length

    difference.times {array << value} 

    array.clone  

end
```

Can anyone help me figure out why it's giving me this error message? I thought that {array << value } was adding new elements to the end of my array inputs. Thank you!

Comment: can you also give the input data array, so that I can run and debug ?

Comment: Your `new_array = array.clone` should go up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your non-destructive version is actually destructive. What you want is probably this:

```
def pad(array, min_size, value = nil)
  pad!(array.clone, min_size, value)
end
```

There's no point in implementing the same behaviour twice. Make one bridge off of the other.

Comment: thank you @tadman I'm days new to Ruby, I was trying to figure out a way to run what you had here, but kept running into errors in my powershell because I was trying to do array.clone.pad!(min_size, value), I see my issue now!

Comment: No trouble at all. If you're feeling adventurous, you can always make these methods part of Array so you can call things like `array.pad(...)` instead. That can clean up your code a lot.